# how to get current Function object reference

Tags: javascript, function, reference

```
itself.bind = function (object, method, callback, context, args, includeEventArgs) {

  var handler, originalArgLen;

  args = args.slice(0, arguments.length);
  originalArgLen = args.length;
  context = context || null;

  handler = function () {
     if (includeEventArgs) {
        for (var i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           args.push(arguments[i]);
        }
     }

     callback.apply(context, args);
  };

  handler.userArgsLength = originalArgLength; 

  object[method] = handler;
};
```

Suppose I call

```
TOOL.bind(canvas, "onmouseover",  doDrawFunc, [currentDrawingTool], true);
```

I want to be able to access `userArgsLength` from from within the `doDrawFunc`.

Answer (score 22):

You are looking for `arguments.callee.caller.userArgsLength`.

- [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) is a reference to `doDrawFunc`.
- [`.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) is the function that called it (`handler`).
- `.userArgsLength` is the property of that function object.

**Edit:** I do not believe there is any way to avoid `arguments.callee` without changing your main function. You probably should be passing whatever the callback needs access as an argument to that callback function anyways. You could even pass in `handler` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; however, arguments.callee is deprecated in some javascript implementations.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the following JSLint error: Problem at line 42 character 7: Avoid arguments.callee.
      arguments.callee.caller.matchCase = matchCase;

Comment: @user562688: Pass whatever you need within the callback into a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment of handler.userArgsLength to an earlier point, shove it onto the apply array stack, and bam, you can assume it's the final argument.

Not sure why you'd wanna use arguments.callee anyway; from what I understand, traversing backwards like that can get really slow if you're not careful.

Comment: i thought about this answer before I posted the question, but this will not work for me: I do not want the user of this library to be surprised by the extra parameter. For example, I want the user to be able to bind the function as myFunc(expectedArg1, expectedArg2,...) NOT myFunc(userArgsLength, expectedArg1, expectedArgs2,...). ALSO, i do not want to use callee because it is deprecated in some versions of javascript. Is there a way to do what I want